# Printf Not Working in Ubuntu

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

So I was required to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time and this is what I basically came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
        int c, i;
        for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
                s[i] = c;
        if (c == '\n') {
                s[i] = c;
                ++i;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
        return i;
}

int reverse(char line[], char reverse[])
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = strlen(line); i < strlen(line); i++, j--) {
                reverse[i] = line[j];
        }
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        int len;
        char line[MAXLINE];
        char rev[MAXLINE];
        while (len = getLine(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
                reverse(line, rev);
                printf("%s\n", rev);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

As far as I know it's fine and should work correctly but when I run it even though the next line gets printed there is no reversed string there!
Same problem persists in other programs as well where I need to print a string, I am not sure if I should ask the question on `askubuntu` forum or here so I gave it a shot here first!

Comment: Do you think the problem is with `printf()` or with `reverse()`? If it's `printf()`, why have you included `reverse()` in the question? If it's `reverse()`, why does the title refer to `printf()`? Write the shortest program you can that shows your problem with `printf()`, or think harder about your `reverse()` function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be `lim - 1` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reverse function, you miss copying the `'\0'` character. This might be causing the printf to not print the string. Please do remember that strlen gives length without the `'\0'`.

Modified Reverse function should be like this:

```
int reverse(char line[], char reverse[])
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = (strlen(line)-1); i < strlen(line); i++, j--) {
                reverse[i] = line[j];
        }
        reverse[i] = '\0'
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that the first iteration copies the terminator at index `0`, so it is an empty string with the reversed string afterwards. Note that `line[strlen(line)]` is the 0-terminator.